Intercept CRM_Core_Exception Object / "You do not have permission to access this content" if CiviMail: view public CiviMail content access disabled
Since public mailings access is disabled, we redirect visitors using .htaccess:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/civicrm/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^civiwp=CiviCRM$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]

which works for URLs like  /civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&amp%3Bq=civicrm%2Fmailing%2Fview&amp%3Breset=1&amp%3Bid=6d47e8e85a237398&amp%3Bcid=6796&amp%3Bcs=820bf263a301eb109a93bbc0ee2076fe_1731450440_168
Still, CRM_Core_Exception Object (CiviCRM error at sitemname (You do not have permission to access this page.) appears in logs and being sent via the CiviCRM Report Error.
What would be the best way to intercept? Should permission issue be considered as exception error at all?
